# Выпадающее меню с поиском и списком городов!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Затея такая:
При клике на поле "Выберите город" выпадает меню, при двойном клике закрывается, при клике вне дива закрывается:
В этом меню сразу идет поиск по городам которые будут ниже, потом идет список городов. Список с городами листается вниз ( справа ползунок прокрутки) Когда делается выбор города он вставляется в поле "Выберите город".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот html:

```html
<div class="b-order-prepare__field" data-qaid="city-dd">
  <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down x-drop-down_state_active" data-qaid="dd_widget"><span class="x-drop-down__value b-order-prepare__field">Выберите город</span><span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span><input type="hidden" value="8e1718f5-1972-11e5-add9-005056887b8d">
    <div class="x-drop-down__dropped">
      <div class="x-drop-down__search">
        <div class="x-input x-input_size_s"><input type="text" class="x-input__field" autocomplete="off" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="x-drop-down__list js-dropdown" style="max-height: 300px;">
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item b-drop-down__list-item_state_hover">Авангард</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Авдеевка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Авиаторское</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Агрономичное</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Аджамка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Ананьев</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Андреевка (Балаклейский р-н)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Андреевка (Бердянский р-н)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Андрушевка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Антоновка (Скадовский р-н)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Антонины</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Апостолово</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Арбузинка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Арциз</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Аскания-Нова</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Аулы</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бабаи</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бабанка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балабино</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балаклея (Черкасская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балаклея (Харьковская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балки (Запорожская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балта</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Банилов</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бар</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Баранинцы (Закарпатская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Барановка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Барвенково</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Барышевка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бахмач</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бахмут</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Баштанка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Безлюдовка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бердичев</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бердянск</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Берегово</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Берегомет</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><noscript></noscript></div>
```

Comment: и чего вы от нас то хотите? если помочь с чем-то, то напишите с чем

Comment: Помочь с функцией, на клик открывает, двойной клик закрывает, клик вне дива закрывает, при открытии меню выпадает поиск и список городов, поиск ищет  по этому списку городов, при выборе города город попадает в поле "Выберите город"! Пример в скринах я указал, буду признателен за помощ!! Сам не справлюсь .. И еще что бы список с городами мог листаться вниз потому что из будет очень много )

Comment: Вот вам [плагин](https://select2.org/dropdown) для этого, а список городов prom скорее всего берет из API Новой почты

Comment: $(".x-order-form-row__field").click(function() {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").toggleClass("x-drop-down__list_active");  
});
            $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.closest(".x-order-form-row__field").length == 0) {
            $(".x-drop-down__list").removeClass("x-drop-down__list_active");
        }
    });   Функция на клик, двойной клик закрывает, клик вне дива закрывает.

Comment: Теперь осталась функция на выбор со списка и выбранный город заходит в поле "Выберите город". И сделать так что бы поле поиска выпадало вместе со списком городов и поиск по городам. И список городов пролистывался вниз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".x-drop-down__value").click(function(event) {
  toggleMenu();
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.b-drop-down__list-item').click(function() {
  $('.x-drop-down__value').html($(this).text());
  toggleMenu();
});

function toggleMenu() {
  let menu = $(".x-drop-down__dropped");
  if (!menu.hasClass('active')) {
    window.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
  } else {
    window.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
  }
  menu.toggleClass("active");
}

function closeMenu() {
  $(".x-drop-down__dropped").removeClass("active")
}

$('.x-drop-down__dropped').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});


$('.x-input__field').on('input', function() { 
  let search = $(this).val();
  searchData(search);
});

function searchData(search) {
  let towns = $('.b-drop-down__list-item');
  towns.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf(search) === -1) {
      $(this).addClass('item_hide');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('item_hide');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.js-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.x-drop-down__dropped {
  display: none;
}

.x-drop-down__dropped.active {
  display: block;
}

.item_hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-order-prepare__field" data-qaid="city-dd">
  <div class="js-toggle x-drop-down" data-qaid="dd_widget"><span class="x-drop-down__value b-order-prepare__field">Выберите город</span><span class="x-drop-down__arrow"></span><input type="hidden" value="8e1718f5-1972-11e5-add9-005056887b8d">
    <div class="x-drop-down__dropped">
      <div class="x-drop-down__search">
        <div class="x-input x-input_size_s"><input type="text" class="x-input__field" autocomplete="off" value=""></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="x-drop-down__list js-dropdown" style="max-height: 300px;">
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item b-drop-down__list-item_state_hover">Авангард</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Авдеевка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Авиаторское</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Агрономичное</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Аджамка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Ананьев</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Андреевка (Балаклейский р-н)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Андреевка (Бердянский р-н)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Андрушевка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Антоновка (Скадовский р-н)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Антонины</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Апостолово</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Арбузинка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Арциз</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Аскания-Нова</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Аулы</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бабаи</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бабанка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балабино</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балаклея (Черкасская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балаклея (Харьковская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балки (Запорожская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Балта</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Банилов</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бар</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Баранинцы (Закарпатская обл.)</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Барановка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Барвенково</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Барышевка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бахмач</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бахмут</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Баштанка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Безлюдовка</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бердичев</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Бердянск</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Берегово</li>
        <li class="js-item b-drop-down__list-item">Берегомет</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><noscript></noscript></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за труд!! Все работает как и хотелось. Очень благодарен!!!

Answer (score 1):

чем обычный инпут с даталистом не угодил?

```
<input list="%идентификатор%">
<datalist id="%идентификатор%">
 <option value="Город1">
 <option value="Город2">
</datalist>
```

Обстилить его чтобы на `<select>` похоже было, и всего делов.

И, да, двойной щелчок на веб-сайте - мракобесие.

Comment: Селект не пойдет! Двойной щелчок( раз - открылся див, два - нажал в том же месте - закрылся! С этим уже разобрался. теперь хочу сделать поиск по пунктам городов и выбор города что бы запрыгивал в поле "Выберите город"

Comment: Вы читать умеете? Это ИНПУТ, а не селект. В сочетании с даталистом он работает как поиск плюс список выбора. При клике на элемент этого списка он "запрыгивает в поле". И открывается-закрывается так, как вы описываете.

Comment: Вот вам даталист, посмотрите: https://jsfiddle.net/vbhgd2dk/

Comment: Очень даже не плохо! Как в этом поле написать подсказку "Выберите город" ? placeholder="Выберите город" разобрался)

Comment: так же, как в обычный текстовый инпут: https://jsfiddle.net/vbhgd2dk/1/

Comment: теперь оформить красиво и готово!

Comment: Такой вопрос, каким образом связать поле "Выберите город" и "Выберите отделение" Когда выбираю город, поле "Выберите отделение" стает активным! Например "Москва" - кликаю в поле "Выберите отделение" и высвечиваются все отделения города москвы куда я могу отправить!

Comment: Ну, это зависит от того как вы вообще задаете список отделений. Если он заранее забит весь и нужно показывать только некоторые, это одно. Если он подтягивается с сервера в зависимости от выбранного города - это другое.

Comment: Если брать список городов и отделений с сервера Транспортной компании, как это сделать? Вот сайт компании [https://devcenter.novaposhta.ua/docs/services/556d7ccaa0fe4f08e8f7ce43/operations/556d8211a0fe4f08e8f7ce45]